# Question about Java class

Tags: java, oop

I am just learning Java as a hobby.

How do I make a class define a field? E.g.

```
private string[] biscuitlist
```

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: Check out the Head First Java book... it's probably the easiest/fastest/most enjoyable way to pick up Java. http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Java-Kathy-Sierra/dp/0596009208

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java is case sensitive. You need to declare it as `String[]`, not as `string[]`.

```
package yourpackage;

public class YourClass {

    private String[] biscuitlist;

}
```

That said, this is actually not "subclassing". So your question title actually contradicts with the question message. To learn more about Java in general, I strongly recommend to go through the [Trails Covering the Basics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/). Good luck.

Comment: the link you gave seems to be a rather good resource many thanks for your help

Comment: Sure, when you want to learn X, start with the documentation/tutorials/guides which are provided with X. In case of Sun Java, that are the Sun tutorials :) Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: a bit off topic...the Trails Covering the Basics page makes my eyes hurt.Am I the only one...full red, full blue, busy page. JavaDocs formatting is a lot better :)

Answer (score 0):

The declaration goes inside the class definition as well.

```
public class SomeClass {

  private String[] biscuitlist;  // declare the variable

  public SomeClass(){}  // empty constructor

  public String[] getList() {
    // the variable is private so provide a getter for external access
    return biscuitList;  
  }
}
```

If you declare the variable private only methods inside the class can access it. Checkout [access controls](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to understand this if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined variable already. Just note,

1. Java is case sensitive.
2. All classes starts uppercase, e.g. `String`, `Date`, `List`, etc by convention.

Answer (score 0):

A class is basically a set of data (fields) and a bunch of operations(methods) on those fields

```
public class yourClass{
    //define fields here
    private String[] biscuitlist;  
    // java will automagically set biscuitlist to a null reference

    //make a constructor for your class if it will ever be instantiated
    public yourClass(){
    }

    //do stuff here (methods)
}
```

So basically defining a field is as simple as typing in the access(public, private, protected) giving it a type (String, int, String[], Object) and giving it a name. if not assigned a value after they will default based on the java API (objects get a null reference, ints get 0 etc.)